# Is there any way to add/print custom step/text in html reports

Tags: spock, geb, spock-reports

I am using athaydes spock-reports. I would like to insert some specific output texts in html reports. For that please refer below things which I have used so far.
Below is my Spec file:

```
@Stepwise
class TC001_SMO_Scenario_Spec extends GebReportingSpec {
def "Step 1:Go to the login page of the WU"() {

        when: "User open the Login page"
        to LoginPage

        then: "Login page should get open"
        at LoginPage

        when: "User enters credentials"
        page.Login()

        then: "Home Page should get open"
        at HomePage
    }

    def "Step 2:User initiates transfer process"() {

        when: "Clicks on the Start New Transfer button"
        page.selectionOfItem()
        sleep(2000)

        then: "Reciept Number should be generated"
        at ManageConnections
        def recieptNumber =  tabConnections.text()
        reportInfo(recieptNumber )       
        reportInfo " Reciept Number is $recieptNumber "
    }
}
```

Now when the execution is done then below is the snapshot of report.

[image]

Now my requirement is that, there is some receipt number is getting generated on web page, I would like to have that to be printed in html report, after the Then block. (then: "Reciept Number should be generated").
Could you please guide me how this can be done with the help of specific geb/spock keywords or athaydes - spock-reports.

I referred the material from below site as well, however it's not working for me.
https://github.com/renatoathaydes/spock-reports#how-to-use-it

Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: what I your use case? If you need proof that the test has been executed the right way, you could take screenshots...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got success and I believe I got the root cause as well.

If the spec file extends to `Specification`, then `reportHeader` and `reportInfo` keywords are working fine.

If you are using geb, by extending `GebReportingSpec`, then `report()` needs to be used to get customized steps to be added in geb spock html reports.

Thanks,
Durgesh